# Why are generator expressions called that?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, terminology, dictionary-comprehension, generator-expression

On one hand we have

- List comprehension `[x for x in range(10)]`
- Set comprehension `{x for x in range(10)}`
- Dict comprehension `{x: x for x in range(10)}`

On the other we have

- Generator expression `(x for x in range(10))`

Why are the first three *expressions* called "comprehensions", while the last one is called "expression"? They are represented almost in the same way, and I guess they also work in a very similar way. Is there any subtle reason behind it? It's just for the sake of curiosity.

References:

- [PEP 289 -- Generator Expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/)
- [PEP 202 -- List Comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/)

Comment: In comprehension, the values are all there in memory at the time of assignment. In generators, the next value isn't calculated until you need it next.

This is useful for when each value requires you to have taken the last value and then perform runtime operations on it.

Comment: See https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201605/generator_comprehensions.html

Comment: @superbrain Thanks!! That's super useful! So basically "Originally comprehension was part of the 'literal display' notion. GenExprs are not displays.". That's why they have different names

Comment: If it helps, I think of list/set comprehensions as generator expressions *inside* a literal, though it's not technically correct.

Answer (score 5):

*Comprehensions* produce new objects that consume the internal `for` loop immediately.  They are "finished" once they run.

*Generators* are lazily evaluated - they return immediately, and return an object which will yield individual values later.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. However, I am aware of what they do, I'm just trying to understand why they have different names. Why aren't they called expressions, for example?

Comment: They have different names because they do different things.  A generator simply generates the values.  A comprehension contains a comprehensive set of those generated values.

Comment: An "expression" is basically anything that has a value.  Very generic programming term.

Comment: @Samwise But comprehensions do return a value, don't they? That's why I did not understand why we can't call them expressions.

Comment: Not all generators are (single) expressions -- you say "generator expression" to refer to a single expression which acts as a generator, distinguishing it from a "generator function", which is composed of multiple expressions that create a generator.  All comprehensions are expressions so "comprehension expression" would be redundant.